# Group items in a Sortable list with jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, grouping, jquery-ui-sortable

I'd like to be able to group items in a sortable list. If I group two items, then those two should be dragged together and be put inside a container that I can style. Those items inside that group should be able to be dragged as well inside the group, but that's just a bonus :)

Does anyone know if this is "possible" jQueryUI Sortables?

Comment: good Q, I was hoping to do it with the :next jquery selector and the sortable 'items' parameter, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using custom selections for my items (adding class "selected") and then added the selected items inside a new LI and UL:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <div>Header</div>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```